# How to list files and folder in Google drive root folder

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

This code is used to show google drive contents in my iOS app. Now I could sign in and show contents by using below query `"mimeType ='\(mimeType)' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"`.

The problem is that it returns all the mp3 files even the ones inside sub-folders, that is not what I want. I want to show the same structure as google drive root. Then when a user enter any sub-folder, I would send another request to retrieve the mp3 files in that sub-folder.

So how could I reconstruct this query to achieve it?

// the code to filter/search google drive files.

```
import Foundation
import GoogleAPIClientForREST

class GoogleDriveAPI {
    private let service: GTLRDriveService
    
    init(service: GTLRDriveService) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    public func search(_ mimeType: String, onCompleted: @escaping ([GTLRDrive_File]?, Error?) -> ()) {
        let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.pageSize = 100
        query.q = "mimeType ='\(mimeType)' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
        self.service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, results, error) in
            onCompleted((results as? GTLRDrive_FileList)?.files, error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` then you are telling it that you only want folders or a specific mime type.

if you do `'root' in parents"` it will return everything with a parent folder of root.

so if you do `'root' in parents" and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` you will get all of the folders that have a parent folder of root.

Comment: Oh! I think `'root' in parents"` means everything in root folder, though this express is ambiguous. It really confuse me at the first look, it is like root in its parents, and who is root's parent? Ok, I get the idea from you, thank you. I should turn it into two steps, please see my update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per DalmTo's answer, I have changed my code and have some test. Now I get what I want.

In short, I split the list file into two steps, first to search with query = `'root' in parents"`, which will list all contents in root folder. Then I do a filter `files?.filter { $0.mimeType == "audio/mpeg" || $0.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}` before passing that data source to another ViewController.

To do this, I get every folders in root and every mp3 files in root, other type of files are ignored. Then if a user enter one folder in root, I would do another http request(file list) to get its content.

###### Google drive API function.

```
import Foundation
import GoogleAPIClientForREST

class GoogleDriveAPI {
    private let service: GTLRDriveService
    
    init(service: GTLRDriveService) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    public func search(onCompleted: @escaping ([GTLRDrive_File]?, Error?) -> ()) {
        let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.pageSize = 100
        // query.q = "mimeType ='\(mimeType)' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
        query.q = "'root' in parents"
        self.service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, results, error) in
            onCompleted((results as? GTLRDrive_FileList)?.files, error)
        }
    }
```

##### call api from a ViewController, and I put a bit context here to make it clear.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        setViews()
        
        // add an observer on notification "userDidSignInGoogle"
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDidSignInGoogle), name: .signInGoogleCompleted, object: nil)
        
        setUpGoogleSignIn()
    }
    
    func setUpGoogleSignIn() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDrive]
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Notification
    @objc private func userDidSignInGoogle(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Update screen after user successfully signed in
        updateScreen()
        print("userDidSignInGoogle")
        listAudioFilesAndFolders()
    }

    func listAudioFilesAndFolders() {
        self.googleAPIs?.search(onCompleted: { files, error in
            guard error == nil, files != nil else {
                print("Err: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                let vc = GoogleDriveFilesViewController()
                // filter the files before passing it.
                vc.audioFilesAndFolders = files?.filter { $0.mimeType == "audio/mpeg" || $0.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}
                UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true)
            }
        })
    }
```