# Drive API v3 or v2, Drive.Files.list to list all PDFs at and below a given targetFolder (including PDFs from sub-folders)

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, search, google-drive-api

I want to use Google's Drive.Files.list(), to list all PDFs in and below a given targetFolder (including PDFs within any/all sub-folders).

The targetFolder happens to be a root folder: GoogleDriveRoot/targetFolder/*.pdf

Is it possible to use query(q) param of Drive.Files.list to accomplish this task in one step? I'm not desiring to loop (DriveApp) as mine is an Apps-Script solution (Google Drive), and exec timeouts are scoffing.

Thanks for any direction or samples!

Comment: In your query you could use: ```parents in '[targetFolderID]' and mimeType='application/pdf'``` however you will still need to loop through if you have subfolders as the parent (folder ID) will change.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68558297/1595451

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to just do a search for all PDFS

```
mimeType='application/pdf'
```

If you add parents you are going to only get files within that file as the parent which means you wont get your sub folders.

Just grab them all and sort it locally.